# How to check in AppDelegate, on start of the application, if the firebase user already exists and is logged in?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, authentication, swift4

I'm developing an iOS App with swift4 and Firebase, I'm searching how to check in AppDelegate, on start of the application, if the firebase user already exists and is logged in?

The situation is:

- user open the app and logged in with username and password and firebase.
- user close the app.
- user reopen the app and if the user was cancelled from firebase, I would to redirect him to login/registration page.

If I use `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser` the user result always logged in, but I have cancelled him from firebase.

Ho can I do that?

Comment: when user gets logged in save  firebase.auth().currentUser in userdefaults and remove it when user logs out, 
in appdelgate check userdefault exist if yes carry to home page if no carry to login page.

Comment: You must get some API from firebase SDK to know user login status, you can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to return boolean if the user is logged in or not.

```
func isUserLoggedIn() -> Bool{
    
    return Auth.auth().currentUser != nil 
         
}
```

then create another function to redirect him wherever you want

```
    func routeInitialVC(with identifier:String ){
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Finally, just use the Boolean function  in your AppDelegate with the ternary operator to make it shorter and apply the routing function

```
        authHelper.isUserLoggedIn() ? routeInitialVC(with: "HomeVC") : routeInitialVC(with: "AuthVC")
```